# Pushing to private docker registry in bash script

Tags: docker

I have a following Bash Script, In order to login into docker private registry:

```
docker login -u ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_LOGIN} --password ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST}
docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST}/testimage
```

However, my code keeps failing with a following error
`Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device`

I have tried to skip that error by adding `| true` to docker login, however it still would just fail with no basic auth credentials when trying to push image. I have also tried to go with `echo "$PASSWORD" | docker login --username foo --password-stdin ${DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST}`

What seems strange for me, as when I totally remove variables from docker login and passing raw values into a script it logins and push docker image without any problems - like `docker login -u user --password password`

Could someone please help, on how to execute successfully with variables docker login in bash script

Comment: Have you tried to print every environment variable like user/pwdhost before? Just to make sure there are real values up there. Cause if password is missing, it will likely ask for it interactively, as you can see.